# Time Machine Purge Backups Older Than

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

Is there a way to configure Time Machine to purge data older than 6 monhts?

I'm trying to use the same Time Capsule for two computers and the first computer is using up 80% of the drive (since I bought it first and have been performing backups on it over a longer period of time.). -- I only need Time Machine to maintain data for 6 months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in solution within Time Machine to do this, but you can manually delete old backups.

From within Time Machine, navigate to the backup you want to remove. From the "Actions" menu in Finder, you will see the option to delete the backup. There is also an option to delete all instances of the file from all of the backups.

Comment: Can you automate this through a script?

Comment: Yes, you can use applescript to launch applications and interact with Finder. Here is a small guide to get you started: http://www.peachpit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Using-AppleScript-to-control-the-Finder

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood correctly, but the solution you proposed can be used to delete a single file from the backup, but how would you delete all files from the backup older than a certain date?